Codex Vaticanus initial text
Could anyone tell me why the first few textual (scripture-containing) pages in the Codex Vaticanus online copy are in cursive? As far as I know, the Codex is dated to the 4th century, at which time the cursive script didn't exist. And the later additions from the 15th century are towards the end (if I'm not wrong).
Can anyone explain this?

There are several interesting facts concerning the Codex Vaticanus and especially concerning the distortions that has been made in this script over the centuries. (Vatican.com)

The Codex Vaticanus was revised in the 8th, 10th and 15th centuries
thus it is not as it was originally.
The entire Codex Vaticanus manuscript has been manipulated; every
letter has been run over with a pen and there are some sentences,
clauses and  even verses that have been omitted.


The codex is defective at the beginning and the end. At the beginning
45 chapters of Genesis are missing, in the middle 10 folios of the
Psalms are missing and at the end the second part of Hebrews, the
Pastorals and Revelation are missing. These missing parts have been replaced in the 15th CE. [2]

According to An Introduction to the Old Testament in Greek. Additional Notes — Henry Barclay Swete:

B (II). CODEX VATICANUS (Vatican Library, Gr.1209).
A MS. of the Old and New Testaments, defective at the beginning and in some other places. The O. T. has lost its first 31 leaves, the original hand beginning at Gen. xlvi.28 (with the words polin eis gen
Rhamesse). Through the tearing of fol.178 2 Regn. ii.5 -- 7, 10 -- 13,
has also disappeared, and the loss of 10 leaves after fol.348 involves
a lacuna which extends from Ps. cv. (cvi.) 27 to Ps. cxxxvii.
(cxxxviii.) 6^b. The longer gaps have been filled by a recent hand.


Genesis 1:1–46:28a (31 leaves) and Psalm 105:27–137:6b have been lost.
These were replaced by pages transcribed by a later hand in the 15th century. (Codex Vaticanus - wiki)

The Codex Vaticanus lost its first 31 leaves, and the original hand begins at Genesis 46:28. Therefore, any content before this point in the current manuscript would be part of the later additions.
Note: A digitalized version of Codex Vaticanus can be viewed online.

Henry Barclay Swete classifies CODEX VATICANUS as an UNCIAL MSS.
The original manuscript was written in uncial script, which is a form of block lettering used from the 4th to the 8th century. (uncial script - wiki)

The Codex Vaticanus is a quarto volume which is written in uncial letters of the 4th century, on folios of fine parchment bound in
quinterns. (Vatican.com)

Uncial

Image II. This image above is taken from page 192 of "Handbook of Greek and Latin Palaeography" by Edward Maunde Thompson. It is a palimpsest fragment of Ciceros' De Republica (4th century).
Correctors:

There are at least two different correctors from the uncial period.
Some corrections are not enhanced by the reinforcer and are therefore
very early. It seems reasonable to assign these to either the original
scribe or a contemporary, who went through the whole codex and
corrected several errors. The second corrector is later and eventually
identical with the reinforcer (9th or 10th CE). There are several
corrections which leave some text unenhanced and substitute a word or
letters. Tischendorf and the ECM date one corrector to the 6th/7th CE.
There are also a few corrections from the minuscule era. [2]

Greek minuscule was a writing style developed in Byzantine manuscripts during the 9th and 10th centuries. It replaced the earlier style of uncial writing and differed in using smaller, more rounded and more connected letter forms, as well as many ligatures. (Greek minuscule - wiki)
History of the codex:

The following is rather clear:

First half of the 4th CE: the codex is written.
4th to 6th CE: small Greek chapter numbers added
5th to 7th CE: Symbols in Acts/Catholics added.
7th - 8th CE: Large Greek chapter numbers added
10th or 11th CE: Complete text reinforced, Skeat: "before the ninth". It is quite a mystery why the text has been so carefully enhanced in this period.
10th to 15th CE: Addition of coloured book headings. (Although the    dates for these things are rather uncertain, the succession is clear.)
15th CE: The restoration took place. The missing pages at the beginning, the end and within the Psalms have been replaced by a minuscule hand. Also the codex was probably newly bound.

The Genesis supplementum has been copied from Codex Chisianus R VI 38 (OT MS 19). Unfortunately nothing is known about the early history of
this MS. The minuscule NT portions could not be identified in any MS.
Also, according to Paul Canart (unpublished researches) the writer of
the minuscule script cannot be identified with any known 15th CE Greek
scribe. [2]

Minuscule

 This image above is a snippet of earliest type of minuscule writing, from a 10th-century manuscript of Thucydides.
